# How can i add subquery result to the end of main query in doctrine 2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

How can i add subquery result to the end of main query result in doctrine 2?

$qb - main query

$sub - subquery

```
public function findPosts(): array
    {
        $ids = '777, 775, 767, 756, 752, 751, 732, 727, 725, 721, 717, 710, 702, 693, 678, 671, 662, 658, 639, 638, 617, 598, 579';
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('article');
        $qb->where('article.visible = 1')
            ->andWhere('article.published_at <= :present_date')
            ->setParameter('present_date', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->orderBy('article.id', 'DESC')
            ->select('article.id', 'article.title', 'article.slug', 'article.slots_type', 'article.skill', 'article.type', 'article.views', 'article.vk_shares', 'article.fb_shares')
            ->leftJoin('article.img', 'image')
            ->addSelect('image.filename AS img')
            ->setMaxResults(30);

        $sub = $this->createQueryBuilder('article');
        $sub->where('article.id IN ('.$ids.')')
            ->andWhere('article.visible = 1')
            ->orderBy('article.id', 'DESC')
            ->select('article.id', 'article.title', 'article.slug', 'article.slots_type', 'article.skill', 'article.type', 'article.views', 'article.vk_shares', 'article.fb_shares');
        return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
    }
```

I tried to use the field function but didn't get the expected result

Comment: As I understand you have 2 options.   The first is to make union all query with https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/native-sql.html 
The second is to merge results in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way is to merge the results of both queries.
As an old user of symfony / doctrine :
First thing i would say. Do not make a function that does two different things as much as you can.
Second, i advise you to not use select() function if it does not impact performance to remove it. It will help you have a better sustainable code. I mean it is optional to use it.

If i understand well your usecase, it is mandatory that the result of your second request need to be at the end of the main request.
You could do a Union, but it will make a query that won't be reusable for other usecase. It's on your own.

Here is my "simple" view of what you could do

```
public function findNewestPosts(): array
{
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('article');
        $qb->where('article.visible = 1')
            ->addSelect('image')
            ->andWhere('article.published_at <= :present_date')
            ->setParameter('present_date', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
            ->leftJoin('article.img', 'image')
            ->orderBy('article.id', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(30);

       return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}

public function findPostByIds(array $ids): array
{
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('article');
        $qb->where('article.id IN ('.implode(',', $ids).')')
            ->andWhere('article.visible = 1')
            ->orderBy('article.id', 'DESC')
        return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Look at :

```
->addSelect('image')
```

It will automatically add image to the main `select *` which is done by removing the `select()` function.
It will prevent automatic subqueries when calling `$article->getImage();` (same if you call it in twig only for example)
For this case it is a good performance optimization, otherwise it will do 1 subqueries for each article.

Then inside your service / controller / whatever :

```
$newestPosts = $yourRepository->findNewestPost();
$fixedPosts = $yourRepository->findPostByIds([1,2,3,4]);
$posts = array_merge($newestPosts, $fixedPosted);
```